# 16.04 vlan manual interfaces not being created out of /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking, 16.04, openstack

Entries like the below (for OpenStack provider networks) worked in 14.04. It doesn't work in 16.04. Although "#vconfig add enp3s0 99" does work, but I need permanent entries.

```
---- /etc/network/interfaces excerpt ----
auto enp3s0.99
iface enp3s0.99 inet manual
    up ip link set dev $IFACE up
    down ip link set dev $IFACE down
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding "vlan-raw-device enp3s0" solves the problem. As in:

```
---- /etc/network/interfaces excerpt ----
auto enp3s0.99
iface enp3s0.99 inet manual
    vlan-raw-device enp3s0
    up ip link set dev $IFACE up
    down ip link set dev $IFACE down
```

Answer (score 1):

Before I could only get it to work using vlan named interfaces.

```
    auto vlan99
        iface vlan99 inet static
        vlan-raw-device eth0
```

I confirmed subinterface notation works as well with more advanced configs;

```
    auto bond1
    iface bond1 inet manual
        bond-mode 4
        bond-miimon 100
        bond-lacp-rate 1
        bond-slaves eno3 eno4

    auto bond1.17
    iface bond1.17 inet manual
        vlan-raw-device bond1
        up ip link set dev $IFACE up
        down ip link set dev $IFACE down

    auto bond1.18
    iface bond1.18 inet manual
        vlan-raw-device bond1
        up ip link set dev $IFACE up
        down ip link set dev $IFACE down

    auto cloudbr0
    iface cloudbr0 inet manual
            bridge_ports bond1.17
            bridge_fd 5
            bridge_stp off
            bridge_maxwait 1

    auto cloudbr1
    iface cloudbr1 inet manual
            bridge_ports bond1.18
            bridge_fd 5
            bridge_stp off
            bridge_maxwait 1`
```